# From compatible Riemannian metric to Hermitian metric

Tags: complex-geometry

By this notes [p.42](http://people.mpim-bonn.mpg.de/hwbllmnn/archiv/kaehler0609.pdf)

[image]

It gives a hermitian metric by a compatible Riemannian metric $g$, and from p.23, it extends $g$ to $T_{\mathbb{C}}M$ complex bilinearly. I wonder if we extend $g$  via the sesquilinear convention, can we still get the same result, which is that we can get a Hermitian metric $h=g+i\omega$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extending $g$ sesquilinearly you get another metric, say $\tilde{g}$, on $TM\otimes \mathbb{C}$ but they are related by $$\left.  \tilde{g}\right|_{T^{1,0}M} = \frac{1}{2}h$$

See Lemma 1.2.17 in page 30 of [Huybrechts' book](https://www.math.uh.edu/~shanyuji/Complex/Complexgeometry.pdf)